# Search function in the API doesn't work as expected

Tags: bug, search, api-v2.2

This looks like an error in the search part of the API.

This search URL:
[/2.2/search?tagged=javascript&intitle=get%20column%20array&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=relevance&tagged=javascript&intitle=get%20column%20array&site=stackoverflow)

doesn't return any answers.

I'm supposed to get this result, at least:
[Get column from a two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848004/get-column-from-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it doesn't appear to say so in [the doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search), **`intitle` expects an *exact phrase*, not a list of words.**

You can currently see this by:
[/2.2/search?intitle=get column array&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=relevance&intitle=get%20column%20array&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

which currently returns one result with that exact phrase in the title, but doesn't return the many questions that have those 3 words in other arrangements.

---

## To search for titles that contain a list of words,

use [the `/search/advanced` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) and pass multiple `title:...` properties in the `q` parameter.

For example:
[/2.2/search/advanced?q=title:get title:column title:array&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=relevance&q=title%3Aget%20title%3Acolumn%20title%3Aarray&tagged=javascript&filter=!9YdnSQHvY&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

which currently returns the question you expect as well as 5 other valid results.